# rc.local python script can't load mysql python connector

Tags: python, mysql, debian

I am running Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi. I have a python script set in `/etc/rc.local` to run when the device is booted. The python script was working as expected until I added mysql functionality to the script. Mysql is correctly installed and configured; the mysql functionality in the script works as expected when run manually from the shell. According to `/var/log/syslog`, the script is unable to find the mysql module:

```
Mar 17 10:18:42 PressPi rc.local[464]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Mar 17 10:18:42 PressPi rc.local[464]:   File "/home/pi/python/switch_counter3.py", line 20, in <module>
Mar 17 10:18:42 PressPi rc.local[464]:     import mysql.connector
Mar 17 10:18:42 PressPi rc.local[464]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

Python import statement :

```
import mysql.connector
```

`/etc/rc.local` entry :

```
python3 /home/pi/python/switch_counter3.py &
```

I also tried :

```
sudo python3 /home/pi/python/switch_counter3.py &
```

I tried to add a **60** second sleep in `rc.local` before the python script was called, in case the script was running before mysql was initialized. I can see in `syslog` that the script is waiting the 60 seconds before running, but I get the same error message.

I could try other methods to automate the script, but I am interested in why the current method is not working as expected.

Comment: It's not complaining that "mysql is not initialized"  It's complaining that the Python module is not found.  Have you installed it?  Have you installed it in Python 3 using `pip3`?

Comment: Yes, mysql is correctly installed. The script loads the msql module and runs all the mysql functionality correctly when run manually from the shell.

Comment: You undoubtedly have a versioning problem.  `/etc/rc.local` is picking up a different `python3` than your command line.  Do you have a bash alias defined?  Do you have a link in `~/.bin` or `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: I have not done any aliasing or linking. this is the output from PYTHONPATH

**rc.local ouput**

`['/home/pi/python', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']`

**shell ouput**

`['/home/pi/python', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']`

Comment: I added `sudo -H -u username` when calling the python script in `/etc/rc.local`. This seems to have completely fixed the issue.

Comment: And do you get why?  Without `sudo`, the package gets installed into your user account.  It isn't available system wide.  It's an easy trap to fall into.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Roberts helped me learn, the `rc.local` script was running as root, but I had installed mysql under my user account. Running from rc.local, the script couldn't find the mysql package. I added `sudo -H -u username` when calling the python script in `/etc/rc.local`, and the script runs as expected.

Thank you to Tim Roberts.

for those interested in the full `/etc/rc.local`. Everything before the sleep statement was default.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi

#make sure mysql has been initialized
sleep 15
#run python script as user pi with python3
#The ampersand allows the command to run in a separate process and continue booting with the process running.
sudo -H -u pi python3 /home/pi/python/switch_counter3.py &

exit 0
```